# How can I share a function variable within a nested function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

UPDATED:

How can I use a function variable within nested function? I've simplified my problem in the following example:

```
def build():
    n = 1 # code to parse rpm package minor version from file
    f = min_ver(n) # update minor version
    return

def min_ver(n):
    n = 2 # this is defined by another process, not set intentionally
    s =  1 + n # still need the original value from build()
    return s
```

The actual use case is that I'm grabbing a parsed rpm package minor version value in ex1() from disk called 'n'. When ex2() is executed from ex1(), it deletes the old package, builds a new rpm package with a new minor version. So when it calls for ex1()'s value within the nested function, it's not changed to the new version.

How can I maintain the original 'n' value within the nested function, before passing onto a new value of 'n' post nested function?

Comment: Nothing is going to change the local scope `n` within `ex1` in the background. If you declare `n` as a global within `ex1` then something else could change it externally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to pass the variable as an argument to `ex2`.

```
def build():
    n = int(1)
    f = ex2(n) # pass the value to the next function
    n = int(5) 
    return 

def min_ver(n_old):
    n = 2
    s =  1 + n_old # use the n that was passed in
    return s
```

Comment: Can you not call `ex2` before the background task changes `n` instead? Otherwise you could save the old `n` to a new variable before it is changed.

Comment: As in my updated answer - if you name the argument to `min_ver` something else, then it will retain that value even if you change `n`.

Comment: Somethings I over complicate things in my head, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help, happens to all of us!

Answer (score 0):

If you make `ex2()` actually nested then you can access the outer variables.

```
def ex1():
    n = int(1)
    def ex2():
        s =  1 + n
        return(s)
    f = ex2()
    n = int(5) # done with nested value, rewrite new value
    return()
```

Also, you probably want to return `f` or `n` instead of an empty tuple, I would imagine.

And you don't need to say `int(1)` you can just say `1`. Everything, including integers and strings, is implicitly an object in python.